# How do I add my work in the staging branch?

Tags: git

At my company we have numerous engineers working on the current project. So we have a master branch that is off limits and develop branch that we work off of. We create feature branches from the develop branch. We do our work and we do a `git rebase develop` from our feature before pushing and creating a pull request. So at this point my feature branch is up to date with the develop. Sometimes it takes a few days to get approval to merge your changes with develop. So another engineer made a staging branch where we can share and demo our new feature. Also the producers can review it there before it is merged to the develop branch.

Question 1)

So my coworker told me to rebase with the staging branch. He said I should `git checkout <staging-area-branch>`. Then `git rebase <my-feature-branch>`. I know that this is adding my feature branch as the new base for the staging branch, but I am not sure why we would do it this way. It would seem to me that we would want to put my feature branch changes on top of the staging branch.

Question 2)

Also, If I were to `git checkout <my-feature-branch>` and then `git rebase <staging-area-branch>` I would replace the base of my feature branch causing me to lose the the ability to merge it easily with develop after my PR is approved, right?

Comment: I think you should go for the merge when dealing with the staging branch. Would be more convenient to ask your coworker as to why he wants to follow this approach. i follow this generally while rebasing  https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing#the-golden-rule-of-rebasing

Comment: This is a quote from the link you attached:  "For example, think about what would happen if you rebased master onto your feature branch." I get a little confused sometimes when I read statements like this in tutorials. I am not sure what 'onto' means in these situations. Does it mean I am in my feature branch and I type `git rebase master`, or I am in my master branch and type `git rebase feature`.

Comment: this means you are on feature branch and the you are rebasing it with whatever is in master branch

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but that seems contrary to the diagram below the quoted statement. The diagram shows the master's commits on top of the feature's commits, which I thought would mean that you are in your master and typing `git rebase feature`. I thought the whole idea of a rebase is to replace the foundation or base that the feature branch sits on (or was created from). So when you are in your feature branch and type `git rebase master` you replace the previous base of your feature branch with the latest master branch.

Comment: yes you are right got me confused as well. so "onto" is basically putting on TOP so therefore you run it on your feature branch mostly and not on public branches like master, to put your feature on top of whatever new base is coming.

Answer (score 0):

> It would seem to me that we would want to put my `feature` branch changes on top of the `staging` branch

Yes: if you were to use rebase, you would need to replay your `feature` branch on top of `staging`, not the opposite.

> Causing me to lose the the ability to merge it easily with `develop` after my PR is approved, right?

Yes. Which means a simple merge to the `staging` branch is enough, no need for a rebase in this scenario.